# Understanding apt search

Tags: apt, search

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Release. On terminal when i type `apt search vlc` i get long list of lines. One line says

```
vlc/focal 3.0.9.2-1 amd64
  multimedia player and streamer
```

Does this means I have VLC installed on my system? My understanding on command '`apt search`' is that it searches installed applications on your system. If my understanding is wrong then please explain the results of '`apt search`' command.

Comment: @guiverc, looks liek the "20" was a typo, since the `apt-search` output shows a "focal" package.

Comment: smaqsood@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Question is fixed.

Comment: How did you come by this understanding that "it searches installed applications on your system"?

Comment: I found this info from one of the answer to a question on this same forum. Plus when i run this command for teamviewer i wasn't getting any response that tells me this is because i don't have teamviewer installed that is why. But at the same time when i run this same command with VLC i get response ( quoted in my question) but i don't have VLC installed.., Everything is just adding to the confusion.

Comment: Which answer to which question? Teamviewer is proprietary and not in the official repos.

Comment: so package has to be in repos to install? I didn't know that... so if the package is not in repos, like teamviewer, then how would I install it? I know there is teamviewer for ubuntu, but how would I know if the package is in repos or not?

Answer (score 3):

No

```
$ vlc
Command 'vlc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install vlc      # version 3.0.12.1, or
sudo apt  install vlc-bin  # version 3.0.11.1-2
See 'snap info vlc' for additional versions.
```

and

```
$ apt-cache search vlc
...
vlc - multimedia player and streamer
vlc-bin - binaries from VLC
vlc-data - common data for VLC
vlc-l10n - translations for VLC
...
```

`apt-cache` searches all the packages available with your current setup.

The command to list applications installed is ...

```
 $ apt list --installed
```

and it will show

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Listing...
accountsservice/groovy-updates,groovy-security,now 0.6.55-0ubuntu13.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acl/groovy,now 2.2.53-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acpi-support/groovy,now 0.143 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acpid/groovy,now 1:2.0.32-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
...
```

Limited to `vlc`:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep vlc    
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
$
```

Comment: Thank you man. you have solved half of my problem. SNAP is what i was missing. typing VLC ton terminal tell me its not installed and how to install it but same trick won't work for teamviewer, Why?.,  You said APT-CACHE SEARCH searches all current packages available on my system then why i don't get any response when i search for teamviewer. does it mean there is no teamviewer for ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Half of the problem is finding correct package name using terminal. Rest is installation which shouldn't be a problem once correct package name is known.

Comment: apt list --installed | grep irfanview

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts. I have Irfanview installed.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the command...

```
dpkg -l PACKAGE_NAME*
```

...if you know the name of the package.

The `*` will also include other, usually related, packages that start with that name.

So, in your case, the command would be:

```
dpkg -l vlc*
```

Comment: dpkg -l vlc*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching vlc*